# sshfs mounts share in read-only mode

Tags: ssh, mount, fstab, sshfs, fuse

I need to mount a share using `sshfs`.

When I mount it using `sshfs` directly, i.e.

```
# sshfs martin@192.168.1.10:/home/data/ -o allow_other /mnt/data/
```

or

```
# sshfs martin@192.168.1.10:/home/data/ -o allow_other,default_permissions /mnt/data/
```

the share is mounted, but only in "read-only" mode. However when I add following line into `/etc/fstab`, and do `mount /mnt/data`, then the share is mounted read-write.

```
# martin@192.168.1.10:/home/data/    /mnt/data  fuse.sshfs  noauto,_netdev,allow_other,default_permissions      0   0
```

Both commands are issued unde root. Why does `sshfs` from the command line mount the filesystem read-only?

How can I mount it read-write using the `sshfs` command?

Comment: using the first option, is the share mounted `read-only` also for `root` or only members of the `users` group?

Comment: @Sebastian - it is mounted `read-only` for root as well.

Comment: What exactly do you meant by “mounted read-only”? Copy-paste the output of `grep /mnt/data /proc/mounts` and `touch /mnt/data/foo` while it's mounted read-only. Also copy-paste the messages from the system logs at the time of mounting and (if there are any) at the time of the write attempt.

Answer (score -1):

You should append undocumented variant **,ro** to **-o allow_other** param

```
# sshfs martin@192.168.1.10:/home/data/ -o allow_other,ro /mnt/data/
```

Comment: The question asks how to mount it read-write. Your suggestion forces a read-only mount.